# include Sencha JS to make a layout window

Tags: extjs

I want to make a moveable & draggable window using Sencha JS 4.x, like: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/window/layout.html

Everything is fine, except the Sencha JS packages I downloaded from http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/ have so so many files, **I dont know which one/ones to deploy on my server, I just need the layout window effect**. Note that all Sencha JS files are awful 316MB.

I dont know if stackoverflow is the right place to ask, but Sencha Forum&contact keeps ignoring me. Any advice will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Ext is pretty complicated, it's best to read up on it a bit. This is a good starting point: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/getting_started

Comment: Seems that I have to save all resources(html/js/css/images) from http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/window/layout.html to my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below link section 3. Deployment.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/guide/getting_started

The tools allow you to generate a manifest of all JavaScript dependencies in the form of a JSB3 (JSBuilder file format) file, and create a custom build containing only the code that your application needs.

Thanks, i hope this will help you!!!

Comment: This is an official solution, I bet. Still Sencha is complex and annoying after hours of reading long documentations, and failures of install Sencha Cmd (which they recommended instead of Sencha SDK) which did not work on unbuntu 64bit. An awful day.